# Apex error when changing something on custom object

Tags: apex

somewhere in this code is something that creates a error when changing something on the Access(custom object)

```
    if(emailMessages.isEmpty()) {System.debug('Email Not Created, Something Missing - sendCaseCeaseNotificationEmail - AccessTriggerHelper');return;}
    List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> emailResults = messaging.sendEmail(emailMessages);
    if(!emailResults.isEmpty()) {
        for(Messaging.SendEmailResult result : emailResults) {
            if(!result.isSuccess())
                System.debug('Failed To Send Email' + result.getErrors()[0].getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is the error recieved]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the Contact's email address might be invalid.

We usually get this error when bounce management is enabled.  When Bounce Management is activated and a user sends an email to an invalid email address, the email bounces back and the user is prevented from sending further mails to that address until it is validated.

You can check the settings here
Go to Setup --> Email Administration -- >Deliverability Check "Activate bounce management" Settings.

Solution for your issue would be

- To correct the email address on the above mentioned Contact. (i.e in error)
- Handle that issue in code by using allOrNone optional parameter of Messaging.sendEmail

Something like this

```
if(emailMessages.isEmpty()){
    System.debug('Email Not Created, Something Missing - sendCaseCeaseNotificationEmail - AccessTriggerHelper');
    return;
} 
List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> emailResults = messaging.sendEmail(emailMessages,false); 
if(!emailResults.isEmpty()){ 
    for(Messaging.SendEmailResult result : emailResults) { 
        if(!result.isSuccess()) {
            System.debug('Failed To Send Email' + result.getErrors()[0].getMessage()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Was going to do so, fixed the issue at hand, thanking you greatly :)